# 2 switches and 2 lights, how to separate?

Tags: electrical, rewire

In my living room, I have 2 lights and 2 switches. Both witches turn both lights on. I want to separate them so that each switch turn on only one light. How is this done? Does this require re-wireing and panel work? Or is this just a matter of disconnecting a wire from one for the switches. Here is a picture of one of the switched. I noticed it has 3 black wires.
[image]

Comment: You will need to run another wire, between one of the switches and one of the lamps. Are you able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could replace both switches with home automation smart switches, wire the lights "always on", but then put micro relay controllers or even micro dimmers in the lights' individual junction boxes.  Then program the physical switches to control the lights you want.

No new wiring needed.  And you can grow the system down the road with remote controllers, motion, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If either switch turns the lights off or on you have a 3-way light switch setup.

Separating them will depend on the configuration of the circuit feed, switches, and the lights themselves.

No, you can't just remove or move one wire. Possibly two or three depending on how it is wired.

A little more involved then you proposed. No "panel work" but definitely some re-wiring.